# Does python serial has a problem on macOS?

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to program esp32 with esp idf. I installed it on my mac os machine.

When I try to compile code with "make" command, I have got that error:

**Pyserial is not installed for /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7. Check the README for installation instructions.**

But, If I want to install pyserial with that code: 
- pip install pyserial

It says me that:

**Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.4)**

How can I solve it?

Comment: Hey! It seems that the `make` command is trying to use Python2.7 (as per the message you're getting). But when you do `pip install pyserial`, you can see it tells you it is installed in Python3.7.

So `pyserial` is not installed in the Python being used for `make`. You should install it in your Python2.7 version or tell `make` to use Python3.7. I do not know how you'd do that, but that's the problem here!

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments? Don’t mess with the system version of Python.